# Custom control error

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am working on this custom control. (I am very new to this part of programming.) I am working on an application that has to be able to format mathematical expressions as the user enters the input in my own custom control. This is how I want the control to look like (this image is made in Photoshop):

[image]

I will not explain the behavior I want it to have, because this doesn't help you, but the idea is that **it is not based on any Windows Control**.

Tis is the code I already have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Support.Components
{
    public partial class PartialExpressionEditor : Control
    {
        public PartialExpressionEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
           base.OnPaint(pe);

           Brush background = Brushes.White;
           pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(background, ClientRectangle);
           background.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to put it in my form, I get this error dialog:

[image]

Where is the problem? Or why this error appears?

Comment: your class shows that your control inherits from `Control` but why you did say `it's not based on any Windows control`?

Comment: BTW, your code seems to look OK to me, except that I would use `using(Brush background = Brushes.White){....}` instead of calling `Dispose()` directly as you did. Could you try removing `Dispose()` or at least try using `using` style?

Comment: by 'it's not based on any windows control', I mean that it is not a button, or a text box, or a checkbox etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are disposing a system brush:

```
// background.Dispose();
```

since you didn't create it:

```
Brush background = Brushes.White;
```

To use your own brush that you dispose yourself:

```
using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.White)) {
  pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

You might have to exit Visual Studio to get your Brushes.White brush back.

Comment: My problem is not when I run the application! It is occurs when I try to drop the control on the form from the Toolbox in VS2010

Comment: @Victor Doesn't change my answer.  Using the control in the designer will run the paint event.

Comment: After your edit, the code works! Thank you very much! I can now... start writing my control :))